# What is the math needed to compute the correct multiplication for any positive or negative value?

Tags: c#, math, division, multiplication

I have a quick-and-dirty utility that takes images and resizes them. It allows the user to select either "increase" or "decrease" bot the height and the width of the image. It seems to work except when "decrease" is selected, and the percent value to decrease is 100 or more. Obviously my code:

```
private void buttonApplyPercentageChange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int origHeight = _imgToResize.Height;
    int origWidth = _imgToResize.Width;
    // Two ways to convert the val
    double heightFactor = (double)numericUpDownHeight.Value / 100.0;
    double widthFactor = Convert.ToDouble(numericUpDownWidth.Value) / 100.0;
    if (checkBoxHeightIncrease.Checked)
    {
        heightFactor = 1.0 + heightFactor;
    }
    if (checkBoxWidthIncrease.Checked)
    {
        widthFactor = 1.0 + widthFactor;
    }
    var newHeight = Convert.ToInt32(origHeight*heightFactor);
    var newWidth = Convert.ToInt32(origWidth*widthFactor);
    textBoxNewHeight.Text = newHeight.ToString();
    textBoxNewWidth.Text = newWidth.ToString();
}
```

...is not taking this specific scenario into consideration.

What must I do to correctly compute the new size regardless of increase/decrease and whether the percentage entered is >= 100?

Comment: Why don't you just scale the image? If the user enters 100% there is no change. If he/she enters 200%, the image doubles in each dimension. If he/she enters 50%, the image is halved in each dimension. Etc. Your current approach admits some ambiguity imo. E.g., what does "decrease size by 100%" mean? Open to interpretation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What must I do to correctly compuete the new size regardless of increase/decrease and whether the percentage entered is >= 100?

```
if (!checkBoxHeightIncrease.Checked && heightFactor > 1 ||
    !checkBoxWidthIncrease.Checked && widthFactor > 1)
{
    // show an error
}
```

You can't decrease an image's width or height more than 100%. Decreasing a dimension by 100% makes it zero. Decreasing it further makes it negative. That's why you're running into trouble.

I suggest you get rid of the increase/decrease checkboxes and let the user just enter a percentage *relative* to the current size (i.e. 100% is no change). Then your code becomes:

```
private void buttonApplyPercentageChange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int origHeight = _imgToResize.Height;
    int origWidth = _imgToResize.Width;

    // Two ways to convert the val
    double heightFactor = (double)numericUpDownHeight.Value / 100.0;
    double widthFactor = Convert.ToDouble(numericUpDownWidth.Value) / 100.0;
    if (heightFactor < 0 || widthFactor < 0)
    {
        // show an error - no negative values allowed
    }
    var newHeight = Convert.ToInt32(origHeight*heightFactor);
    var newWidth = Convert.ToInt32(origWidth*widthFactor);
    textBoxNewHeight.Text = newHeight.ToString();
    textBoxNewWidth.Text = newWidth.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if( heightFactor > 0 )
{
  textBoxNewHeight.Text = newHeight.ToString();
}
else 
{
  textBoxNewHeight.Text =origHeight.ToString(); 
}

if( widthFactor > 0)
{
  textBoxNewWidth.Text = newWidth.ToString();
}
else
{
  textBoxNewWidth.Text =origWidth.ToString(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the user from selecting a number below the last valid value of -100, just change the min value property on your numeric edit boxes `numericUpDownHeight` and `numericUpDownWidth` in the form designer to -100.

As others have stated, you cannot calculate a whole number (0, 1, 2, ... no negatives or fractions) that is less than 100% smaller than the original, and you're going to need a whole number to resize to.

Answer (score 0):

What does it mean to decrease the size of an image by more than 100%? If you decrease it by 100% the size becomes zero. Decreasing by more than that would be meaningless, because you can't have an image with negative height and width. I would show a dialog box telling the user that they can't decrease the size by more than 100% (if `heightFactor < 0 || widthFactor < 0`).

Comment: Nice comment. Not an answer to the question asked, though.